# No such column 'ActivitySubtype' on sobject of type Task

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I am new to salesforce development, I am trying to get the user information on entering the phone number from my contacts which is successfully done.
I want to create a call log on getting the user information such as in below image. The task is generated when I omit the CallType and ActivityType  fields but the log is created under '**Activity Timeline**' tab

[image]

My code is as following

```
$url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Task";

  $content = json_encode(array(
    "Subject"=>'Call',
    "WhoId"=>$name,
    "Status"=> 'not started', // or 'Completed',
    "Description"=>'Description it is',
    "Priority"=>'Normal',
    "CallType "=>'Outbound',
    "ActivityType"=>'Call',
    "ActivitySubtype"=>'Call'

  ));


$curl = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,

   array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",

     "Content-type: application/json"));

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

  $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

  $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  if ( $status != 201 ) {

   die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));

 }
```

I am getting this error

Error: call to URL https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Task failed with status 400, response [{"message":"No such column 'ActivitySubtype' on sobject of type Task","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}], curl_error , curl_errno 0

[image]

i have looked up into this link for reference

[link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lookedupfromactivity.htm)

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it.

I searched for the api versions which are currently available 
, altered the version to 40.0, removed attributes "CallType, ActivityType, ActivitySubtype " and added "TaskSubType"=>'call'. It logged a call.

Might help others facing same issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using long old version `20.0`.

Prefer to use latest version like this:

https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Task

You should get desired result.

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000228387&language=en_US&type=1)

The field with API name ActivitySubtype is visible in API version 35.0 and above for the object named AcitivityHistory.
It Provides standard subtypes to facilitate creating and searching for specific activity subtypes. This field isn’t updateable.

Comment: the error is also getting for "CallType " and "ActivityType" fields

Comment: What is the error you are getting for these fields.

Comment: this one.... Error: call to URL https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Task failed with status 400, response [{"message":"No such column 'CallType ' on sobject of type Task","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}], curl_error , curl_errno 0